# javascript innerHTML is returning text instead of html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, text, innerhtml

Im doing an application in angularjS and i have this function to remove #(hashes) and combine them into links.

```
$scope.getAllHashes = function(event){

    var x = event;
    var collect = '';
    var link = '';

    for (i = 0; x.length > i; i++) { 

        //remove #
        link = x[i].substr(1);

        collect += "<a href='#/search/" + link + "'>" + x[i] + "</a> ";

    }
    return document.getElementsByClassName('hashes').innerHTML = collect;
};
```

Its returning text:

```
<a href='#/search/aaa'>#aaa</a> <a href='#/search/bbb'>#bbb</a> <a href='#/search/cccc'>#cccc</a>
```

instead of links:

```
#aaa #bbb #ccc
```

the source is coming from this array:

```
$scope.events = 
[
    {

            id: 1,
            datetime: 'FRI, 6 NOV 10:00 AM',
            title: 'Event Title goes here - lalelalela',
            address: {
                road: '650 Address Rd',
                city: 'Toronto',
                state: 'Ontario',
                postal: 'A1B1C3',
                country: 'CA'
            },
            hashes: ['#aaa','#bbb','#cccc']

    }, .....
```

This is the code from html source code

```
<span class="hashes ng-binding">
            &lt;a href='#/search/aaa'&gt;#aaa&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href='#/search/bbb'&gt;#bbb&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href='#/search/cccc'&gt;#cccc&lt;/a&gt; 
</span>
```

Im not sure why its displaying as text instead of html.

Comment: I assume you're using ng-bind or {{}} to output the html with angular, right? that only outputs text. If you want to output html, you'll have to use the correct directive. also probably a bad idea to be changing the innerHTML of an element within a controller function. You should either be updating the data, or outputting the result from the function directly within the view.

Comment: <span class="hashes">
                {{ getHashes({ data: eventObject.hashes }) }}
 </span>

Comment: then yes, you can't output html that way, only strings. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: im just calling the function. what is adding the data is pure javascript. within the function. it was working before when i was using #id instad of .class . There are better ways for sure to do that. but im wondering why it works with ID and not with CLASS

Comment: Because by id you get a DOM Node that has an innerHTML property, and by class you get a DOM Node Collection that ***does not*** have an innerHTML property.

Comment: oh thx Kevin i didnt know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTML you need to use ng-bind-html

```
<p ng-bind-html="getHashes({ data: eventObject.hashes })"></p>
```

Make sure you and including a dependency on ngSanitize. See the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: Also... it isn't clear why you are doing this: return document.getElementsByClassName('hashes').innerHTML = collect;

Comment: fist think i thought doing :D i will change it latter. better way to do it

Comment: is doest work btw. callikng the function inside the ng-bind-html .. @mcgraphix